# Tanaka-kun Is Always Listless has a decimal volume number? Volume 13.5?

Tags: tanaka-kun-is-always-listless

I did a double-take, but it looks like [*Tanakeda* volumes 13 and 13.5 are to be released simultaneously](https://twitter.com/ganganonline/status/1170895140354834432). Volume 13.5? A decimal volume number? I mean, I've seen decimal chapter numbers in *Nichijou*, and decimal game series numbers in *Touhou*, but this is the  first time that I've seen a decimal volume number...

[image: 田中くんはいつもけだるげ 13巻＆13.5巻 2冊同時発売 特集！！]

According to the Tweet, 13.5 is going to be some kind of memorial book. Is it known what kind of content is going to be in this book? Is there some kind of special occasion that prompted the release of this unusually numbered volume?

Comment: Considering vol. 13 is the actual last volume, looks like 13.5 is more like an omake...

Comment: As Aki has mentioned, the .5 means that the volume is an "omake". These usually contain short side stories or alternate endings, I don't know what the Tanaka one has specifically.